# Const before or after the type?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
string const& operator[] (size_t index) const { return elems[index]; }
```

should it not be:

```
const string&
```

?

Comment: Makes no difference here.

Comment: In its purest form, it should come after to keep things consistent. The fact that it can go on the left is the exception, really. That said, I personally prefer left.

Comment: I think it's easier to read type names if you put it on the right, but it makes no difference.

Comment: In the first case, read the type from 'right to left' "Reference to a const string".  Some people advocate ALWAYS using right to left notation as we then have consistency.  I lean towards supporting that idea, but probably wouldn't be found manning the barricades.

Comment: http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/17/continental-const-placement/

Comment: @BoBTFish: thanks! I was about to post that, too ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Cv-qualifiers like `const` apply to whatever is to the left of them, unless there is nothing, in which case they apply to the right. For `string const&`, the `const` applies to the `string` to its left. For `const string&`, the `const` applies to the `string` to its right. That is, they're both references to `const` `string`, so in this case, it makes no difference.

Some people prefer to have it on the left (like `const int`) because it reads from left to right. Some people prefer to have it on the right (like `int const`) to avoid using the special-case (`int const * const` is more consistent than `const int* const`, for example).

Comment: What is `const int* const` and `int const * const`....?

Comment: @user2745266 They are both `const` pointers to `const` `int`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I wanted to ask was how both the `const` are applied in those two cases (which one is for int and which one for pointer). May be I should have asked in proper way. Thanks.

Comment: @user2745266 As I described at the beginning of my answer, the `const`s apply to whatever is to the left of them, unless there is nothing, in which case they apply to the right. So the first `const` in both of them applies to the `int`, and the second `const` applies to the `*`.

Comment: The real argument for putting the `const` systematically to the right is when typedefs are involved: given `typedef int* pInt;`, both `const pInt v;` and `pInt const v;` mean the same thing: `int* const`.  This is not what most people would expect from the first, however.

Comment: Wow I've been confused about the semantics of declarations with multiple `const`s for almost a year now and you simply saying "`const` applies to whatever is to it's left unless there is nothing in which case is applies to what is to its right" has just completely cleared up all of my confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

The `const` can be on either side of the data type so:

“`const int *`” is same as “`int const *`”

“`const int * const`” is same as “`int const * const`”

```
int *ptr;           // ptr is pointer to int
int const *ptr;     // ptr is pointer to const int
int * const ptr;        // ptr is const pointer to int
int const * const ptr;  // ptr is const pointer to const int
int ** const ptr;       // ptr is const pointer to a pointer to an int
int * const *ptr;       // ptr is pointer to a const pointer to an int
int const **ptr;        // ptr is pointer to a pointer to a const int
int * const * const ptr;    // ptr is const pointer to a const pointer to an int
```

The basic rule is `const applies to the thing left of it. If there is nothing on the left then it applies to the thing right of it.`

Answer (score 3):

It works either way in that context, and is a matter of personal preference and coding conventions.

Some programmers prefer to put it *after* the type name so that it's more consistent with other uses of `const`. For example, if you're declaring a pointer where the pointer itself (rather than the pointed-to type) is to be `const`, you need to put it after the asterisk:

```
string * const ptr;
```

Similarly, if you're declaring a `const` member function, it needs to go after the function declaration; e.g.:

```
class Foo
{
    void func() const;
};
```